# In Python, one long file or rather multiple small?

Tags: python

I have just started learning Python, and my question is that is that is it better/faster to divide my code into multiple small parts into separate files and then import them, or just put everything into one long file and call it a day?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/139869/62878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you like to work and what the purpose of the code is. Personally, I like to divide my program into individual scripts that each do a specific thing. This allows me to keep track of everything better and isolate any potential issues. I have a teammate who does everything in one script, however, and I'll do this too if the script is short enough.

If you want to import your own code from other files, make sure they share a source directory and that the source directory is well specified, otherwise your Main script will not be able to locate the imports.